# Snappy Compression

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, parquet, snappy

I am trying to store an avro file as a parquet file with snappy compression. Although the data gets written as a parquet with the filename.snappy.parquet but the file size remains the same. Pasting the code.

CODE:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","snappy") 

orders_avro.write.parquet("/user/cloudera/problem5/parquet-snappy-compress")
```

Answer (score 0):

Snappy compression is the default in parquet-mr (the library that Spark uses to write Parquet files). So the only thing that changes here is the filename.